# When using a "share" feature what is typed in the caption to include the users new score?

Tags: ios, objective-c, share

I have created a "Share" button in my app so you can send an automated caption to others through message, Facebook, twitter, etc... What do I type in the caption that allows the user to send his/her current score? I know there's something simple that people type like "%d" that grabs the score and places it inside the message.

Thank you.

```
   else if ([touchedNode.name isEqualToString:@"share"]) {
      [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"coin.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];

      NSString *caption = @"Yo check out my new score "%d" ! ";

      UIImage *imageToShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"banner.png"];
      NSURL *urlToShare = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=949315818&mt=8"];

      NSArray *activityItems = @[caption, urlToShare, imageToShare];
        UIActivityViewController *vc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
        UIViewController *root = self.view.window.rootViewController;
        [root presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
NSString *caption = @"Yo check out my new score "%d" ! ";
```

With this:

```
NSString *caption = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Yo check out my new score \"%d\"!", currentScore];
```

`NSString`'s `stringWithFormat:` allows you to interpolate values into strings in complex ways.

The `\`'s are necessary to escape the double quotes inside a string delimited with double quotes.